# Predicting weekly volume by category in R

Tags: r, prediction

I am relatively new to using predictive modeling and would like some brainstorming help/assessment of feasibility.

I currently have the following variables in the data set for 2018-present with  one row per order

- date
- day of week
- item category
- order id
- lat / long for shipping address.

I would like to predict weekly sales for the remaining weeks of this year BY item category. I am most comfortable using R at the moment.

What algorithm/package would you recommend I look into given that I would like to predict weekly sales volume by category?

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer is you start with a set of tidyverse packages. `group_by()` from dplyr is very powerful for computing values by some factor. To me, it sounds like you have your data in a tidy form already which works best with tidyverse framework as it allows one to easily vectorize operations over data.frame. Check out the main packages they have to offer and their overviews [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/). Start with simpler models like `lm()` and then if the need arrives continue with more advanced ones. Which one of the variables are you going to use as predictors?

No matter the model you choose, after you build the appropriate one, you can use built-in `predict()` together with `group_by()` function. More details on basic prediction [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/166-predict-in-r-model-predictions-and-confidence-intervals/).

By the way, I can't see the data set you talk about, only the description of it. Could you provide a link to a representative sample? It would allow me to provide deeper insight.